# SQL update statement with different table in from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Out of accident I noticed that the following query is actually valid:

```
UPDATE bikes
SET price = NULL
FROM inserted
WHERE inserted.owner_id = 123456
```

This is part of a trigger where someone forgot to join the original table to the `inserted` table. The result is that when the trigger is executed, all prices are set to `NULL`.

The correct SQL statement is this:

```
UPDATE bikes
SET price = NULL
FROM inserted
     INNER JOIN bikes ON bikes.id=inserted.id
WHERE inserted.owner_id = 123456
```

How/why is this first statement valid?

Comment: WHERE is just a boolean expression. You could also use `WHERE 1=1` or `WHERE 1=0`. They're all valid - there's no rule about having to have a valid join

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? It seems very weird, since as one looks at the statement, it would seem not valid. It looks like one is trying to update a table that isn't even part of the query (because of the from clause).

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly They obviously didn't judge it worthwhile to introduce warnings/errors for every case where someone like your colleague can program something silly, e.g. querying other tables but never using them. Such time is better spent on improving people's ability to do useful things, not preventing them from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: If you apply it to the official T-SQL definition https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx it's perfectly valid. You're correct that it doesn't make sense. But again the WHERE is a logical expression that results in true/false and it's up to the programmer to get that expression right.

Comment: If you look in the query plan (CTRL-L) you _might_ find a warning in there.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thanks. I looked at the query plan. It has no warnings, but an index seek (costs 0%) on the second table that is not used after all.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Good summary; that's the crux of it. One can equally write things like `join` `on @unrelatedVariable = GETDATE()`, which is valid grammatically, despite being semantically useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be valid?  SQL Server doesn't know what you're trying to do.  It thinks you want to update all of the fields where some condition exists on another table.  ***See the last update below.***

**SETUP**

```
declare @table table
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)
declare @itable table
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)

insert into @table (id, name)
select 1,'abc' union 
select 2,'def' union 
select 3,'ghi' union 
select 4,'jkl' union 
select 5,'mno' union 
select 6,'pqr'

insert into @itable (id, name)
select 1,'abc' union 
select 2,'def' union 
select 3,'ghi' union 
select 4,'jkl' union 
select 5,'mno' union 
select 6,'pqr'
```

**All names on @table will change to zzz**

```
update @table
set name = 'zzz'
from @itable i
where i.id = 1

select * from @itable
select * from @table
```

**All names where id = 1 on @table becomes yyy**

```
update @table 
set name = 'yyy'
from @itable i 
inner join @table t on i.id = t.id
where i.id = 1

select * from @itable
select * from @table
```

**This will NOT update anything**

```
update @table
set name = 'aaa'
from @itable i
where i.id = 133

select * from @itable
select * from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement does not work as expected because it is missing the entire INNER JOIN line with the bikes and inserted table. Without that SQL Server will update all rows as all rows will qualify for an update when the inserted.owner_id = 123456.

You can reproduce this outside of the trigger in TSQL like :

update bikes set price =null
from SomeOtherTable
where SomeOtherTable.SomeColumn = 'some_value_that_exists'

This is syntactically valid statement in SQL Server. If the Intention is to update bikes table based on existance of a row in some unrelated table that cant be joined because the 2 tables arent related then this is how you would do it. But that is not your requirement. Hence why it updates all records instead of only those that match the bikes.id In programming terms this is called as a logical bug.

The inner join makes it more restrictive and forces to to update only those rows that match the join condition between the 2 tables (bikes.id=inserted.id comparison )

Answer (score 1):

In Simple terms the from clause is optional..Consider below query..

```
update table 
set id=10
```

This has one table right after update clause ,sql just updates it..

now consider below query..

```
update table1
set id=40
from table2..
```

What do you think SQL does,it updates all the rows same as first query..

unless you refer to another table in from clause and join like below

```
update t1
set t1.id=40
from 
table1 t1
join
table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

below is the from clause explanation in update syntax stripped down to show only to relevant parts..

> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object being updated appears more than one time in the FROM clause, one, and only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All other references to the object in the FROM clause must include an object alias

As long as above rules are valid (as in your case),SQL will happily update table found immediately after update clause